# How to change names of a list of numpy files?

Tags: python, numpy

I have list of numbpy files, I need to change their names, In fact, let's assume that I have this list of files:

```
AES_Trace=1_key=hexaNumber_Plaintext=hexaNumber_Ciphertext=hexaNumber.npy
AES_Trace=2_key=hexaNumber_Plaintext=hexaNumber_Ciphertext=hexaNumber.npy
AES_Trace=3_key=hexaNumber_Plaintext=hexaNumber_Ciphertext=hexaNumber.npy
```

What I need to change is the number of files,  as a result I must have:

```
AES_Trace=100001_key=hexaNumber_Plaintext=hexaNumber_Ciphertext=hexaNumber.npy
AES_Trace=100002_key=hexaNumber_Plaintext=hexaNumber_Ciphertext=hexaNumber.npy
AES_Trace=100003_key=hexaNumber_Plaintext=hexaNumber_Ciphertext=hexaNumber.npy
```

I have tried:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import struct
path_For_Numpy_Files='C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy'
os.chdir(path_For_Numpy_Files)
list_files_Without_Sort=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
list_files_Sorted=sorted((list_files_Without_Sort),key=os.path.getmtime)
for file in list_files_Sorted:
    print (file)
    os.rename(file,file[11]+100000)
```

I think that is not the good solution, firstly It doesn't work, then  it gives me this error:

```
os.rename(file,file[11]+100000)
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that you can do this in one line, or with `regex` but I think that clarity is more valuable. Try this:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy'
file_names = os.listdir(path)

for file in file_names:

    start = file[0:file.index("Trace=")+6]
    end = file[file.index("_key"):]
    num = file[len(start): file.index(end)]

    new_name = start + str(100000+int(num)) + end

    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, new_name))
```

This will work with numbers >9, which the other answer will stick extra zeros onto.

Comment: Thank you. but  it gives me this error:     start = file[0:file.index("=")+1]
      ValueError: substring not found

Comment: @user6652926 - I have updated my answer to be more complete. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I am sorry, It was my mistake, I put the wrong format of the file,hexnumber= f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f  for example

Answer (score 1):

Your `file` variable is a `str`, so you can't add an `int` like `10000` to it.

```
>>> file = 'Tracenumber=01_Pltx5=23.npy'
>>> '{}=1000{}'.format(file.split('=')[0],file.split('=')[1:])
'Tracenumber=100001_Pltx5=23.npy'
```

So, you can rather use

```
os.rename(file,'{}=1000{}'.format(file.split('=')[0],file.split('=')[1:]))
```

Comment: Thank you but it gives me the same error os.rename(file, '{}=1000{}'.format(*file.split('=')))

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Then you have some file name that is not in the expected format. Print the file name and check the erroneous one.

Comment: I am sorry, It was my mistake, I put the wrong format of the file,hexnumber= f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f  for example

Comment: Updated my answer.